# Swap column values for selected rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I need to clean a dataset, there are some columns with errors since their values are exchanged because `b` can not be larger than `a`, I've created a column called `wrong_data` and it has a True value anytime this happens:

```
   df['wrong_data'] =  (df['a'] < df['b'] )
```

Now I want to exchange the data in `a` and `b` whenever the condition is met, so whenever `wrong_data = true` holds.

So far, I have tried:

```
df.at[wrong_data = true, 'a'] = b
df.at[wrong_data = true, 'b'] = a
```

But apparently the syntax is wrong and I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: You can just sort I think for an easy solution - `df[['a','b']] = np.sort(df[['a','b']],axis=1)[:,::-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow!

I think that you can omit the third column. Have you tried the following:

```
wrongDataIdx = (df['a'] < df['b'])
df.loc[wrongDataIdx, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[wrongDataIdx, ['b', 'a']].values
```

This should solve your issue. Happy to hear some constructive feedback!

Tested:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,3,2]})
>>> wrongDataIdx = (df['a'] < df['b'])
>>> df.loc[wrongDataIdx, ['a', 'b']] = df.loc[wrongDataIdx, ['b', 'a']].values
>>> df
a  b
0  4  1
1  3  2
2  3  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a couple of `np.where` statements:

```py
df['a'] = np.where(df['wrong_data'] == True, 'b', 'a')
df['b'] = np.where(df['wrong_data'] == True, 'a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `wrong_data` column.

Try this:

```py
df[["a", "b"]]=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted([x.a, x.b])), axis=1)
```

Sample input:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(data={"a": [1,5,7,9,11], "b": [2,3,10,-6,2]})

print(df)

df[["a", "b"]]=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted([x.a, x.b])), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
  a   b
0   1   2                                                   
1   5   3                                                   
2   7  10                                                   
3   9  -6                                                   
4  11   2                                                      
  a   b                                                    
0  1   2                                                    
1  3   5                                                    
2  7  10                                                    
3 -6   9                                                    
4  2  11                                                   
 [Program finished]
```